# jqGrid dynamic event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Suppose I have the following (shortened for simplicity):

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
...
ondblClickRow: function() {
    // I want to define this function dynamically at run time
}
...
});
```

How to I bind ondblClickRow event outside of the grid Deceleration. For example in jQuery I would normally do

```
$('#grid').bind('ondblClickRow', function() { alert('my over written event'); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to override event handlers with setGridParam

Something like this:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ 
    ondblClickRow: function() { alert('my over written event'); }
});
```

See docs:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: Excellent, thank you that works perfectly.   I did see that before but I could not find it again.

Comment: Sweet. jqgrid is awesome, nobody can deny!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever successfully used setGridParam for the subGridRowExpanded event?

[jqGrid method setGridParam on event subGridRowExpanded causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188359/jqgrid-method-setgridparam-on-event-subgridrowexpanded-causes-error)